# layer-list behaves strangely (inncorrectly) on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, layer-list

Basically I'm making a time indicator for a timetable. It's the pink bar in the screenshots. I tested on my nexus 9 first and everything is as it should be but on my galaxy s4 (4.3) it displays completely wrong..
https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/mf0bjuneBY3pTPiyRFPrrtNY17LBgJK9/Screenshot_20160323-011338.png
https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/Xdulw1OzHZTukPEouDy2RVIbA8svnvVV/Screenshot_2016-03-23-01-13-30.png

Each column is a relative layout.

The indicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/time_slider"
    android:background="@drawable/time_indicator_view" />
```

time_indicator_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#66444444"/>
        </shape>
        <size
        android:width="12dp"
        android:height="12dp"/>
    </item>
    <item android:width="8dp" android:height="8dp"
            android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#FF1166"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:height="2dp" android:top="5dp" android:left="6dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="#FF1166"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Everything else scales perfectly. What is going on here?

Comment: I tested on a moto G android 6.0 and it displays fine.... just my s4